# Python / BeautifoulSoup - Extract div content checking h1 text

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have an html page like this:

```
<div class="class1">
   <div class="head">
      <h1 class="title">Title 1</h1>
   <div class="body">
<!-- some body content -->
   </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="class1">
   <div class="head">
      <h1 class="title">Title 2</h1>
   <div class="body">
<!-- some body content -->
   </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I need to extract content from the `div` with `class body` only if the title is equal to "`Title 2`". Since their parent containers doesn't have specific ids or classes, the `h1` text is the only way to recognize what's all the div is about. At the moment I use this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifoulSoup

# code to open the webpage
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
body_content = soup.findAll('div', {'class':'class1'})[1]
```

But this isn't very elegant, since it supposes that the div I'm interested in is always the second one of the page - it doesn't check for the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the only solution I can think of is like below:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
    result_tags = soup.find_all(name='div',class_='class1')
    body_content = [tag for tag in result_tags if 'Title 2' in tag.prettify()][0]
```

It is better than your original codes since it does not assume your target div is the second one of the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
html = '''<div class="class1">
   <div class="head">
      <h1 class="title">Title 1</h1>
   <div class="body">
<!-- some body content -->
   </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="class1">
   <div class="head">
      <h1 class="title">Title 2</h1>
   <div class="body">
<!-- some body content -->
   </div>
   </div>
</div>'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
soup.find(lambda tag: tag.get('class')==['class1'] and 'Title 2' in tag.text)
```

or:

```
def T2_tag(tag):
    return tag.get('class')==['class1'] and 'Title 2' in tag.text
soup.find(T2_tag)
```